# Template-of-enum function called generically

Tags: c++, templates

I have such workflow step functions templatized by an enum:

```
template< eSimulationMethod SIM > void DoStep1( const ParamHolder& in, OutputHolder& out );
template< eSimulationMethod SIM > void DoStep2( const ParamHolder& in, OutputHolder& out );
```

I would like to be able to call these generically in a workflow-like fashion (this includes turning the runtime enum to a compile-time parameter in a switch). I tried this:

```
template< template<eSimulationMethod> class WSTEP >
void DoApply( WSTEP step, const ParamHolder& in, OutputHolder& out )
{
    switch(   in.sim_ )
    {
    case ehs:   step< ehs            >( in, out ); break;
    default:    step< enohsnoreorder >( in, out ); break;
    }
}
```

Calling place:

```
DoApply( DoStep1, in, out );
```

This doesn't compile. How to use template-templates in such a scenario? Any better way to come up with a combination of runtime-to-compile_time conversion and genericity?

Comment: `template< template<eSimulationMethod> class WSTEP >` -> `template< typename WSTEP >` should do what you want.  If you want to restrict `WSTEP` then you need to use SFINAE.

Comment: Not quite. error: no matches converting function DoStep1 to type void (*)(const struct ParamHolder&, struct OutputHolder&)
note: candidate is: template<eSimulationMethod SIM> void DoStep1(const ParamHolder&, OutputHolder&).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass templated function template.
You might wrap in a class:

```
template< eSimulationMethod SIM > void DoStep1( const ParamHolder& in, OutputHolder& out );
template< eSimulationMethod SIM > void DoStep2( const ParamHolder& in, OutputHolder& out );

struct DoStep1Runner
{
    template< eSimulationMethod SIM >
    void run(const ParamHolder& in, OutputHolder& out) const
    {
        DoStep1<SIM>(in, out);
    }
};

struct DoStep2Runner
{
    template< eSimulationMethod SIM >
    void run(const ParamHolder& in, OutputHolder& out) const
    {
        DoStep2<SIM>(in, out);
    }
};
```

Then pass that object to your method:

```
template <typename T>
void DoApply(const T& runner, const ParamHolder& in, OutputHolder& out )
{
    switch(   in.sim_ )
    {
        case ehs:   runner.template run<           ehs>(in, out); break;
        default:    runner.template run<enohsnoreorder>(in, out); break;
    }
}
```

Calling place:

```
DoApply(DoStep1Runner{}, in, out);
```